# Clicking arcs in Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I have An array called cities which contains object that represent cities with their cartesian points. These cities are queried from a Database and then drawn in the canvas(which works fine) and pushed in this array. Now I want to click on these points and I want to alert("hello") for testing purposes.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
});
$(document).click(function(e) {
    newx=x;
    newy=y;
    for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
        if ((newx <= cities[i].x+3) && (newx >= cities[i].x-3) && (newy <= cities[i].y+3) && (newy >= cities[i].y-3)) {
            alert(cities[i].name);
        }
    }
});
```

this is my code for the event. For now I will only get a reaction when I am clicking in the +x and -y region from my point to the edge of the canvas.

please help

Answer (score 2):

**Hit testing city-circles on a canvas**

To check if the user clicked in one of your city-circles, use this Pythagoras-related hit-test:

```
var dx = cityCenterX – clickX;
var dy = cityCenterY – clickY;
var radius=cityRadius;
var IsInCity = (dx*dx+dy*dy)<(cityRadius*cityRadius);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Bgh9d/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // define some cities
    var cities=[];
    cities.push({x:100, y:75,  radius:50, name:"large city"});
    cities.push({x:200, y:100, radius:30, name:"medium city"});
    cities.push({x:150, y:150, radius:25, name:"small city"});

    // draw cities
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    for (var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cities[i].x, cities[i].y, cities[i].radius, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      // get canvasXY of click
      canvasMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canvasMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // test if we clicked in any cities
      for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
          var dx=canvasMouseX-cities[i].x;
          var dy=canvasMouseY-cities[i].y;
          var isInCity=(dx*dx+dy*dy)<(cities[i].radius*cities[i].radius);
          if(isInCity){
              alert("You clicked in the "+cities[i].name);
          }
      }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythagoras was a choice fella and all but maybe try the **isPointInPath** method.

You didn't say, but if you're drawing your cities to your canvas using a "path" (context.beginPath, context.moveTo, context.lineTo, etc) you should have a look at the in-built isPointInPath method.

You call the method with the x, y point.

```
if(context.isPointInPath(50, 150)) {
     alert('In path);
}
```

Check out [this link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1966262&seqNum=2) for an example.